# Ember dynamically update template (array item)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using Ember version 2 and have my component template as below;

```
{{#each info as |item|}}
    <span class="value">{{item.value}}</span>
    <span class="label">{{t item.label}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

Now I want to write values to it dynamically (i.e. assume it is a dynamic total which initially is 0 & updates automatically based on user selection of some rows)

My question is while the below code works;

```
var info = self.get('gridParas.info');
info.popObject();
info.pushObject({
    label: 'MyTotalField',
    value: total
});
self.set('gridParas.info', info);
```

This does not work;

```
var info = self.get('gridParas.info');
info.label = "MyTotalField";
info.value = total;
self.set('gridParas.info', info);
```

Is the popObject(), pushObject() the correct way ? What is wrong with the 2nd approach ?
I wanted to avoid pop, push each time.

Comment: You can do `self.set('gridParas.info.label', "MyTotalField")` and `self.set('gridParas.info.value', total)`.

Comment: Not sure if that would work since "info" is actually an array

Comment: Just tried that...while it seems to update the label/value, it does not get reflected on UI (like it does when doing push/pushObject)

Comment: If info is an array it should be `info[0].label` and `info[0].value` assuming info has only one element.

Comment: That does not work...gives Uncaught Error: Property set failed: object in path "gridParas.info[0]" could not be found or was destroyed.

Comment: check this https://ember-twiddle.com/a622768f91572a94938c

Answer (score 0):

the `set()` methods notifies the model that a property has changed, triggering the template to update. Instead of using it, you can call `notifyPropertyChange('info')` or `notifyPropertyChange('info.label')` after you update the label and value, which should update the template. More info can be found in the docs here:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_notifyPropertyChange

Comment: It's useful to know about `notifyPropertyChange`, but it's needed only in specialized cases. How would it help here? Also, `info` is an array. The `label` property is on the elements of the array, not the array itself as I understand it. Nor is `info.label` referenced in any way by the template. So I doubt if a `notifyPropertyChanges` on it would do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the properties directly on the last element, without popping and pushing:

```
var info = self.get('gridParas.info');
info.getObjectAt(info.get('length') - 1).setProperties({
  label: 'MyTotalField',
  value: total
});
```

Or, if you don't want to reuse the current last item, use `replace`:

```
info.replace(info.get('length') - 1, 1, [{
  label: 'MyTotalField',
  value: total
}]);
```

As you can see, you need to pass `replace` the index, the count of items to be replaced, and **an array** of new items to stick in there.

In any case, you do not need this:

```
self.set('gridParas.info', info);
```

Because that's already `gridParas.info`'s value.